# $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{3\sin^2(2x)}{x^{1/2}}\,dx$. Converges or diverges?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{3\sin^2(2x)}{x^{1/2}}\,dx$$

Can I use C.T. for numbers that are not to infinity?

Attempt:

For $x \in (0, \pi]$, $$f(x) = \frac{3\sin^2(2x)}{x^{1/2}} \geq 0.$$

For $x \in (0, \pi]$, $$f(x) = \frac{3\sin^2(2x)}{x^{1/2}} \leq \frac{3}{x^{1/2}} = g(x).$$

Consider $\int_{0}^{\pi} g(x)\,dx$

$$3\lim_{A\to0^+} \int_{A}^{\pi} \frac{1}{x^{1/2}}\,dx=3 \lim_{A\to0^+} 2x^{1/2}\bigg|_{A}^{\pi} = 6\pi^{1/2}.$$

Therefore $\int g(x)\,dx$ converges and by comparison test so does $\int f(x)\,dx$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: ${3\sin^{2}\left(2x\right) \over x^{1/2}} \sim 12 x^{3/2}$ as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Alternatively*, by the change of variable
$$
u=x^{1/2}, \quad 2du=\frac{dx}{x^{1/2}},
$$ one gets
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{3\sin^2(2x)}{x^{1/2}}dx=6\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi}} \sin^2(2u^2)\:du
$$ the latter integral does exist since the integrand is *continuous* over $[0,\sqrt{\pi}]$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at this is to observe you have
\begin{align}
\int^\pi_0 \frac{3\sin^2 2x}{x^{1/2}}\ dx  = 12\int^\pi _0 x^{3/2}\left(\frac{\sin 2x}{2x}\right)^2\ dx = 12\int^{\pi}_0 x^{3/2}\operatorname{sinc}^2(2x)\ dx
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
f(x) = x^{3/2}\operatorname{sinc}^2(2x)
\end{align}
is continuous. Hence the integral is finite.

Comment: Well I think you need bounded and continuous?

Comment: @DHMO We have a compact interval.

Answer (score 0):

The only place
where there could be problems
is around $x=0$
because the function 
is bounded away from $0$.

Around $0$,
$\sin(x) = O(x)$,
so
$\sin^2(2x) = O(x^2)$
so that
$\sin^2(2x)x^{-1/2} = O(x^{3/2})$
which is integrable
around $0$.

So the integral exists.